# SlimFramework Redirect Problems

Tags: php, redirect, slim

i'm trying to manage a login page with redirect to home page if it is still logged:

```
$app->get("/",function() use ($app){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['group_id'])){
        View::login(); // Show login page
    }else{
        $app->redirect('home/'.$_SESSION['group_id']); // Go to home -> This works!
    }
});
$app->get("/home/:group_id",function($group_id) use ($app){
    if(isset($_SESSION['group_id'])){
        if($_SESSION['group_id'] == $group_id){
        View::home();
        }else{
        $app->redirect('home/'.$_SESSION['group_id']); //-> This doesn't work! It goes to mydomain/home... and not to mydomain/mypath/home...
        }
    }else{
        $app->redirect('/'); // This doesn't work! It goes to the root path of my webserver     
    }

});
```

Comments in code talks about my problem. Can someone help me? :)

Comment: Make sure you are calling session_start at the top of your page. What do you get if you if you var_dump $_SESSION?

Comment: i call session_start and $_SESSION gives the correct value..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved in this way:

```
$app->get("/",function() use ($app){
    if(!isset($_SESSION['group_id'])){
        View::login(); // Show login page
    }else{
        $app->redirect('home/'.$_SESSION['group_id']); // Go to home -> This works!
    }
});
$app->get("/home/:group_id",function($group_id) use ($app){
    if(isset($_SESSION['group_id'])){
        if($_SESSION['group_id'] == $group_id){
            View::home();
        }else{
            $app->redirect('../');
        }
    }else{
        $app->redirect('../');   
    }

});
```